# Searchify results not showing up

Tags: search

I have installed Searchify on a HTC Legend running Froyo. Unfortunately, it none of the commands are appearing in search. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled Searchify as a 'Searchable Item' under the global search settings?

Comment: To do this in Froyo, press the search button from the home screen to bring up the Quick Search Box, then press MENU, then Search Settings. You then have to go into Serachable Items and make sure Searchify is checked.